# Why is array.fill() not returning the modified array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const array = ["apple"];
const paddedArray = array.fill("pear", 1, 3);
console.log(paddedArray.length);
```

Logs `1`.

The `Array.prototype.fill()` [type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/8c34b56cde00b5479fb2c85f94fa8be83e28b06a/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1901-L1909) mentions:

> Changes all array elements from `start` to `end` index to a static `value` and returns the modified array

Why isn't the modified array being returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Array#fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) does return the modified array. It is easy to check:

```js
const array = ["apple"];
const paddedArray = array.fill("pear", 1, 3);
console.log(paddedArray.length);    // 1
console.log(array.length);          // 1
console.log(array === paddedArray); // literally the same object
```

**But `.fill()` does not grow the array.**

Only values be between the indexes `0` and `length-1` are filled. From MDN, [the description of the `start` and `end` parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#parameters) (respectively, second and third parameter) is:

> `start` *Optional*
>
> Zero-based index at which to start filling, converted to an integer.
>
> [...]
>
> - If `start >= array.length`, no index is filled.
>
> `end` *Optional*
>
> Zero-based index at which to end filling, converted to an integer. `fill()` fills up to but not including end.
>
> [...]
>
> - If `end >= array.length` or `end` is omitted, `array.length` is used, causing all indices until the end to be filled.
>
> [...]

Then [the description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#description) reads:

> The `fill()` method is a mutating method. It does not alter the length of `this`, but it will change the content of `this`.